# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl, ruby-on-rails-2

I have two servers, each running a Rails application (MyApp). One of these servers manages to fetch a wsdl, and the other does not. I have no idea what to do about my error message. Can any one suggest a change to try?

I have already compared the contents of /etc/ssl/certs on the two machines, and they appear to be identical.

On both machines, SSL handshake succeeds with `openssl s_client -connect ws2.agencyworks.com:443 -ssl3` but fails on Server 2 when `-ssl3` is not specified. (Alternative to `-ssl3`, `-tls1` succeeds on both machines.)

Is there a way to specify a default ssl version for openssl?

A barebones example (Ruby 1.8.7):

```
http = Net::HTTP.new 'ws2.agencyworks.com', 443
http.use_ssl = true
http.get '/EServices/services/StatusSession/wsdl/StatusSession.wsdl'

# Server 1 returns => #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
# Server 2 errors out: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
```

Is there a way to specify ssl version in net/http for Ruby 1.8? (I have not found one.)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question of setting a default ssl version for openssl, either at the system level or Rails level, but there is something you can do...

In Ruby 1.8, an instance of `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext` is what net/http objects use to hold parameters for openssl, but net/http doesn't give you direct access to this instance variable, and it provides no accessor for `:ssl_version`, so there isn't an obvious solution. However, **you can set ssl_version** even in Ruby 1.8 with the following slightly kludgey solution:

```
Net::HTTP.ssl_context_accessor 'ssl_version'    # create accessors for ssl_version
http = Net::HTTP.new 'ws2.agencyworks.com', 443 # build http object
http.ssl_version = :TLSv1                       # set ssl_version
http.use_ssl = true
http.get '/EServices/services/StatusSession/wsdl/StatusSession.wsdl'
```

The first line above allows you to set the ssl_version on the OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext instance which your Net::HTTP instance uses.

### Additional Info

**No application-wide solution.** Preferably, you could set this for your whole application with `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:ssl_version] = :TLSv1`, but it turns out that the `DEFAULT_PARAMS` are applied *only if* `set_params` is called on the `SSLContext` instance, and net/http does not do so (in Ruby 1.8, at least). So this application-wide solution is a no-go.